# организация Djnago urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Было так...

корневой urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('account/', include('accounts.urls'), name='account'),
]
```

условный accounts.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^signup/$',accounts_views.signup, 
        name='signup'),
    re_path(r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), 
        name='login'),
    re_path(r'^logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),
        name='logout')
]
```

в данной вариации все работает, ссылка `{% url 'login' %}` отлично отрабатывает, но мне захотелось указать `app_name=account` в `accounts.urls.py` соответственно и переходить по ссылке вида `{% url 'account:login' %}`. как я не пробовал, ничего не работает. Постоянно получаю ошибку - ***Reverse for ‘login’ not found. ‘login’ is not a valid view function or pattern name.***
Подскажите как в данном случае, правильно организовать мои urls.py, что бы все работало?

Answer (score 0):

При подключении новых приложений к Django-проекту их `urls.py` через инструкцию `include` включаются в головной urls.py проекта. Но если в разных приложениях будут `path()` с одинаковыми `name`, то возникнет проблема: при обращении по такому «дублирующемуся» `name` всегда будет вызываться `path()` из того `urls.py`, который в головном `urlpatterns`  подключён ближе к началу списка.

Избегать таких коллизий помогает параметр `namespace` (англ. «пространство имён»). Его передают третьим параметром при подключении `urls.py` приложения через `include`. Обычно для `namespace` указывают имя, совпадающее с названием приложения.

В корневом `urls.py` нужно указать не `name` а `namespace`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

и в `accounts.urls.py` нужно указать `app_name = 'account'`

Comment: я так тоже пробовал. но почему то когда перехожу по ссылке {% account:login %}, получаю ошибку django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'signup' not found. 'signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что откуда у вас импортируется, отредактируйте вопрос, попробуем разобраться, ошибка говорит, что функция не найдена по данному пути, плюс у вас url - login, а в ошибке signup

Comment: У вас view файл называется accounts_views?

Comment: разобрался. в некоторых шаблонах html была ссылка типа {% login %} вместо {% account:login %}. спасибо Вам добрый человек, за желание помочь.